# Variable error rate of SVM Classifier using K-Fold Cross Vaidation Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, fold, cross-validation

I'm using K-Fold Cross-validation to get the error rate of a SVM Classifier. This is the code with wich I'm getting the error rate for 8-Fold Cross-validation:

```
data = load('Entrenamiento.txt');
group = importdata('Grupos.txt');
CP = classperf(group);

N = length(group);
k = 8; 
indices = crossvalind('KFold',N,k); 
single_error = zeros(1,k);
    for j = 1:k 
        test = (indices==j);
        train = ~test;
        SVMModel_1 = fitcsvm(data(train,:),group(train,:),'BoxConstraint',1,'KernelFunction','linear');
        classification = predict(SVMModel_1,data(test,:)); 
        classperf(CP,classification,test); 
        single_error(1,j) = CP.ErrorRate;
    end
confusion_matrix = CP.CountingMatrix 
VP = confusion_matrix(1,1);
FP = confusion_matrix(1,2);
FN = confusion_matrix(2,1);
VN = confusion_matrix(2,2);
mean_error = mean(single_error)
```

However, the `mean_error` changes each time I run the script. This is due to `crossvalind`, which generates random cross-validation indices, so each time I run the script, it generates different random indices.

What should I do to calculate the true error rate? Should I calculate the mean error rate of `n` code executions? Or what value should I use?

Comment: They are all the true error rate. It's safe to just accept one of them. you can increase `k` to get the errors more close (if they are not). What are the ranges of error rates?

Comment: The range of the error rate is 0.0785, and the variance is 1.3103e-04.

Comment: The error rate is fine I believe. You can choose one result or maybe get mean over some but it's not necessary. Maybe using `rng` can help you to get a fixed randomization. Actually the purpose of cross-validation is to shuffle the data once not many!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)),

> In k-fold cross-validation, the original sample is randomly partitioned into k equal size subsamples.

and

> The k results from the folds can then be averaged (or otherwise combined) to produce a single estimation.

So no worries about different error rates of randomly selecting folds.

Of course the results will be different.

However if your error rate is in wide range then increasing `k` would help.

Also `rng` can be used to get fixed results.